# Changing the WebResource.axd URL

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

ASP.NET automatically includes the following script tag:

```
<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=8H_C0aee9xE8e9a-3YoRhA2&amp;t=633413907763620168" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However the clients site is being proxied through another site. So the URL to the root of their site is:

```
http://domain.com/somename/
```

So I need to prefix the WebResource.axd with /somename so the resulting tag will look like this:

```
<script src="/somename/WebResource.axd?d=8H_C0aee9xE8e9a-3YoRhA2&amp;t=633413907763620168" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What I am not sure is how to actually set this? Is there a web.config setting I can set so it has this prefix?

Answer (score 2):

I think that this function **Response.ApplyAppPathModifier("You path");** can make the work for you.

on **Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string HereIsMyFileName = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;

   if HereIsMyFileName contains the "webresource.axd"
     then change it to what ever you like using
        Response.ApplyAppPathModifier("You path");
```

Hope that this helps.

Comment: Didn't work for me, then used solution similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536536/change-the-requested-url-of-webresource-axd

Comment: @anre Thank you for the information. I see the answer you note, and I never go there, to scan and replace the full page html for a string. Too much memory, time, and probably errors if you change something else. Now I do not know why this is not work for you, its 4 years answer.... if I find the time I will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're pretty much screwed here. Reflector reveals with all certainty that this is hard-coded and cannot be changed.

Your only option is to find a workaround. For example, you can create a filter (HttpFilter) that would replace "WebResource.axd" with appropriate address.

Another thing I can think of - if you control the proxy server, you could have it filter out such requests and redirect them appropriately based on Referrer.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can **catch the output stream** and **search/replace** "/WebResource" with "WebResource" or with the path you need...

Try the solution from here: [Change the requested url of WebResource.axd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536536/change-the-requested-url-of-webresource-axd)