# App Relative path to physical path in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I simply try to convert `"~/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?imgid=310aa01d42ba47e1af090c60b520dd8e&type=rbi"` this path to physical path.

I simply tried below code but it throws Exception and says "Illegal characters in path".

```
Server.MapPath("~/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?imgid=310aa01d42ba47e1af090c60b520dd8e&type=rbi")
```

I am not exactly sure it is possible to do that or not.

Edit: I actualy have RadBinaryImage That holds the url. I want to have byte array from RadBinaryImage and this is what i try to access file.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Server.MapPath("~/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd") + "?imgid=310aa01d42ba47e1af090c60b520dd8e&type=rbi)"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [`[control].ResolveUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx) instead?

`MapMath` is looking for a file, which `&` is not accepted in a file path. You're just looking to get the "absolute URL" (or at least one that's folder agnostic) that the client can use.

Comment: Hey i actualy have RadBinaryImage control that holds that url. The thing i want to have Byte Array of image. Is there a quick way ?

Comment: So you want, from that relative URL, to make a pseudo-client call and retrieve the data (image) back as a byte[]?

Comment: @AnyOne: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536536/change-the-requested-url-of-webresource-axd) as it may be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

`Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd` is not physical resource, so it hasn't an equivalent on disk. Probably is loaded/readed from a dll by its corresponding handler.